# Placeholder info not showing in Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a page I am building using Bootstrap 5.2 which includes the following code snippet:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-floating">
    <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Name" name="Company_Name" placeholder="ACME, Inc.">
    <label for="Company_Name">Company Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-floating">
    <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Website" name="Company_Website" placeholder="www.acme.com">
    <label for="Company_Website">Website</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-floating">
    <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Contact_Person" name="Contact_Person" placeholder="Joe Smith">
    <label for="Contact_Person">Contact Person</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-floating">
    <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Email" name="Company_Email" placeholder="joesmith@acme.com">
    <label for="Company_Email">Company Email</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-floating">
    <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Telephone" name="Company_Telephone" placeholder="999-999-9999" />
    <label for="Company_Telephone">Contact Telephone :</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to display placeholder info for each input field when there is no data for that field, but none of the placeholders show up when the form is displayed:

[image: Screenshot of code output]

I look at the code source in Chrome, and it shows the placeholder info, but it isn't showing up.  Is there something with using the `form-floating` class for field labels that could be causing this? If not, does anyone have any ideas on the issue here?

Comment: The labels essentially act as the placeholders for the floating labels -- what exactly are you hoping to show in the placeholders that isn't already visible in the label?

Comment: So, you can't have the descriptive label and then a placeholder to show example input?  I was hoping to be able to display both.

Comment: not without some customising -- this isn't how it would work by default -- I can write some custom CSS for you in an answer

Comment: That would be helpful if you're willing to.  Thank you!  Make sure to post it as an answer so I can accept it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of custom CSS this is easy enough, I've included a `<span>` in the `<label>` which will then disappear when you have filled in a value

If you want the placeholder to disappear on focus then refer to the CSS code -- you can uncomment the last part

```css
.form-floating { overflow: hidden }
.form-floating label {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.form-floating label>span {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 250ms 0ms ease-in-out;
}

.form-floating>.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown)~label>span { opacity: 0 }


/* If you want placeholder to disappear on focus then uncomment below */
/* .form-floating>.form-control:focus~label>span { opacity: 0 } */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Name" name="Company_Name" placeholder="Company Name">
      <label for="Company_Name">Company Name <span>ACME, Inc.</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Website" name="Company_Website" placeholder="Website">
      <label for="Company_Website">Website <span>www.acme.com</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Contact_Person" name="Contact_Person" placeholder="Contact Person">
      <label for="Contact_Person">Contact Person <span>Joe Smith</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Email" name="Company_Email" placeholder="Company Email">
      <label for="Company_Email">Company Email <span>joesmith@acme.com</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Company_Telephone" name="Company_Telephone" placeholder="Contact Telephone" />
      <label for="Company_Telephone">Contact Telephone <span>999-999-9999</span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why, but it isn't working in my page.  I added the CSS to the stylesheet and ran the page (making sure to do a hard reload) and it still isn't showing the placeholder info.

Comment: Check the markup -- the placeholder text now lives in a `<span>` tag inside the `<label>`

Comment: I made the change but it still isn't working.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, it clearly works in the snippet. Maybe you have other styles conflicting or something??

Comment: Can you give me a link or something?

Comment: There is no CSS related to the ```form-floating``` class or the ```input``` or ```label``` markup.  I have a CSS file that adjusts ```nav``` and ```bootstrap-table```, but that's it.  This isn't on a public server for me to give you a link.

Comment: So, it would appear that as long as the ```form-floating``` class is put first in the class declaration, it works.  For example, I had it as ```<div class="col-sm-12 form-floating">```, and it didn't work.  When I transposed the classes, it works.  Odd, but it seems to be ok.

Comment: Very weird, that shouldn't be a thing?  so long as it's working now I guess. I'll update my snippet to include your column classes again -- you need to wrap an extra div around the label and input so the column styles don't affect it

Comment: @FrontRangeGuy the snippet has been updated, I included a bit more CSS to account for the smaller **Contact Telephone** field -- so that the placeholder won't wrap onto a new line and the overflow is hidden. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: No problem!  The only issue it does create is that it allows fields to be empty and passed ```'required''' validation without values.  I wonder why...